# how to find out what versions of a package from a launchpad repository are available with apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, launchpad

If I go to the following web page

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+publishinghistory

there are a number of versions of gedit listed for the distribution "raring" (3.6.0-0ubuntu1, 3.6.1-0ubuntu2, 3.6.1-0ubuntu3, and 3.6.2-0ubuntu1), however, when i issue the command "apt-cache -f showpkg gedit", the only version it lists is "3.6.2-0ubuntu1". The "Synaptic Package Manager" GUI also only lists this version. How do I know what versions are available for download using the syntax explained in the question

[How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version)

by looking at the launchpad.net web page listed above?

My ultimate goal is to learn how to specify a specifc version of a package to install from an older release than what I have installed, but I can't even figure out how to install a different package version on the release I am already running.

Note, I am just using gedit as an example here because it is a package that I found to have multiple versions listed on launchpad.net for the release "raring". The package I really want to install is https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/3.0.2-2ubuntu8/+build/3485589, but it is also of a different release, so I decided to try the simpler gedit case which is of the same release. The latest gnome-disk-utility package has a very dumbed down user interface and many features removed (although some new features have been added). I can manually install the old gnome-disk-utility version by downloading .deb files and installing them by double clicking, but I want to be able to do everything using apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

To get all versions available to install with apt-get, you can use the command:

```
apt-cache madison <package>
```

Example:

```
$ apt-cache madison mercurial
mercurial | 2.8.2-1ppa2~precise1 | http://ppa.launchpad.net/tortoisehg-ppa/releases/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
mercurial | 2.0.2-1ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
mercurial | 2.8.2-1ppa2~precise1 | http://ppa.launchpad.net/tortoisehg-ppa/releases/ubuntu/ precise/main Sources
```

As you see, there's version 2.0.2 from official ubuntu archive, and version 2.8.2 from mercurial PPA.

You can install exact version like that:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mercurial=2.0.2-1ubuntu1
```

Comment: The command that you have shown (apt-cache madison <package>) doesn't give any more information than the command presented in my question (apt-cache -f showpkg <package>). If you want to use your example, how do I select a specific version from the list at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mercurial/+publishinghistory ? As stated in my question, a big part of my uncertainty is how to install a version from a different release that what I am running.