# Unmet dependencies using aptitude to install bind9

Tags: apt

I am getting error while trying to install bind9 on ubuntu 12.04 I did

```
sudo aptitude install bind9


The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bind9{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 336 kB of archives. After unpacking 962 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bind9 : Depends: libbind9-80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed.
         Depends: libdns81 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed.
         Depends: libisc83 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed.
         Depends: libisccc80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed.
         Depends: libisccfg82 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed.
         Depends: liblwres80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed.
         Depends: bind9utils (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but it is not going to be installed.
Internal error: the solver Install(avahi-daemon:i386 0.6.30-5ubuntu2 <libnss-mdns:amd64 0.10-3.2 -> {avahi-daemon:amd64 0.6.30-5ubuntu2 avahi-daemon:i386 0.6.30-5ubuntu2}>) of a supposedly unresolved dependency is already installed in step 21
Internal error: the solver Install(lsb-base:amd64 4.0-0ubuntu20 <avahi-daemon:i386 0.6.30-5ubuntu2 -> {lsb-base:amd64 4.0-0ubuntu20 lsb-base:amd64 4.0-0ubuntu20.2}>) of a supposedly unresolved dependency is already installed in step 37
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     bind9 [Not Installed]                              



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

how should I proceed here?

**answer to a comment below**

```
sudo apt-cache policy bind9 libbind9-80
[sudo] password for deel: 
bind9:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4
  Version table:
     1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
libbind9-80:
  Installed: 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5
  Candidate: 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5
  Version table:
 *** 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: @Braiam I have updated answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is rather simple, somehow you installed a superior version of some of the bind dependencies that are not in the main repository. The way to solve it is to make aptitude to downgrade the packages.

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install bind9=1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4 libbind9-80=1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4 libdns81=1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4 libisc83=1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4 libisccc80=1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4 libisccfg82=1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4 liblwres80=1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

If you want to make aptitude solve the dependencies himself, you only have to say `n` to the question:

> Keep the following packages at their current version:
>
> 1)     bind9 **[Not Installed]**
>
> Accept this solution?

Then aptitude will offer another solution, being the important where it says "downgrade". As you can see the solution offered keeps bind9 uninstalled, that's why you end without installing it.

> how did you reached at conclusion that the packages I have are not in repositories is it because of .dfsg.P1 extensions or some thing else?

`apt-cache policy` lists the origin and version of any packages, which in your case were only in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, which is interpreted as that the package only exist locally and in no other repositories. A example of a package that indicates is in both the repositories and locally:

```
apt-cache policy aptitude
aptitude:
  Installed: 0.6.8.1-2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 0.6.8.1-2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 0.6.8.1-2ubuntu2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

As you can see, the same version is in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: ok how did you write bind9=<something> and in rest of packages what  does it mean and how did you reached here that removing this will resolve

Comment: I noticed that you used -u in aptitude man page says `Begins updating the package lists as soon as the program starts.` which package list is this talking and about which program is this referring to, more over how did you reached at conclusion that the packages I have are not in repositories is it because of .dfsg.P1 extensions or some thing else?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/92021/169736 , and I don't remove anything but downgrade it, what are packages lists is answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/355947/169736). Check my answer to see how I determinated that those packages aren't in your repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Press `n` when it asks if you accept the solution (Y/n/q).
Aptitude will offer a new solution, and then hit `y`. 
It will likely work!

Cheers,