# How to install Python3.3.5 on Ubuntu Server 12.10?

Tags: software-installation, python

I need Python 3.3.5 on Ubuntu Server 12.10.

I want to run `apt-get install python3` but I am not sure this will lead to Python3.3.5 version installation.

In other words: how can I install the exact Python version I need through the command line ?

Comment: you might want to take a look at these: [How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version), [How to install a specific version of a Debian package using apt-get](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/03/how-to-install-specific-version-of.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be absolutely sure that you are installing python3.3.5 then

- Download [python3.3.5 source tarball](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.5/Python-3.3.5.tgz) to `~/Downloads` Folder
- make sure you have already removed `python3` from the system

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge python3
  ```
- Change directory to Downloads

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  ```
- Untar the file

  ```
  tar -xvf Python-3.3.5.tgz
  ```
- Change directory to Python-3.3.5

  ```
  cd Python-3.3.5
  ```
- run install-sh as root

  ```
  sudo ./install-sh
  ```

This should do the job, hope it works

Comment: this manual method I know it, but i wanted to use apt-get install instead. Thank you anyway

Comment: checkout this ppa : `ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes` it has python3.3.5 and all other versions. but it doesnt have python3.3.5 for 12.10

Comment: the link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version arskasra gave me showed me the answer. Thank you, regards