# Install MySQL 5.5 and Tomcat 6

Tags: 12.04

what version of Ubunt need but install MySQL 5.5 and Tomcat 6?

Thanks

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version

Answer (score 1):

After Ubuntu 12.04, all the versions supports mysql 5.5 and tomcat6 [(reference 1)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=mysql) [(reference 2)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&section=all&arch=any&keywords=tomcat&searchon=names)