# Install Apache 2.2.22 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2

There are a ton of resources to which none of them are useful on how to install Apache 2.2 from Precise (12.04) on ubuntu trusty (14.04).

Can someone please help with a detailed answer of how to install Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

When I do an apt-cache there is no Apache 2.2.

When I add the sources, I then get Apache 2.2 but trying to install that does not work.

Apache 2.2 dependencies rely on `apache2.2-common` which relies on `apache2.2-bin`.

So I tried installing `apache2.2-bin` --> `apache2.2-common` --> `apache2-mpm-worker` then `apache2={version}`.

But every time after installation it tells me it failed. When I restart it tells me it failed and it could not read something out of the configuration file because it was missing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to install it running the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 apache2.2-common=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 apache2.2-bin=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 apache2-mpm-worker=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7
```

Thanks to this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version)

**Update:**
It seems like 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 does not exist any more. Please try using 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10

With my original question I have since found the original problem while downgrading so did not look into this problem any further since then.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I got the following:
`E: Version '2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7' for 'apache2' was not found`

Comment: Did you add sources to 12.04 distribution?

Comment: Need to add Ubuntu precise sources and do an update.

Comment: I have added the following sources (https://gist.github.com/rokcarl/d9299393721214646e8fbe92ee25595c) to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before trying this command. I'm on 14.04 though.

Comment: I did the same. Did u review the link in the answer?

Comment: I did, still the same issue.

Comment: Try http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/apache2 - 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10. Sorry for the late reply was sleeping haha. Invite me to a discussion if you are still struggling later on and ill see if I can help you.

Comment: E: Version '2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10' for 'apache2' was not found

Comment: @BraianMellor You might need to find the versions available on ubuntu's website, I know its frustrating when these post's do no work anymore due to the time that has passed. there was most likely a upgrade or downgrade on 2.2 which gives it a new number, You can try and see if there is 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.9 available.

Answer (score 4):

How to install Apache 2.2 on an Ubuntu distro that does not have it in the repositories.

**Requirements**

You need to have the build-essentials package installed to do this.

```
~# sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

To give Apache the ability to compress output to browsers that support it, you need to install zlib. Download the current release from the [zlip Hompage](http://www.zlib.net/) (zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz as of writing), extract it, navigate to the extracted folder, build, and install.

```
wget http://www.zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
tar -xvf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.2.11/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

**Install Apache 2.2**

Download the curent version from the [Apache Download Page](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache22) (httpd-2.2.32.tar.gz as of writing), extract it, navigate to the extracted folder, build, and install.

```
wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.2.32.tar.gz
tar -xvf httpd-2.2.32.tar.gz
cd httpd-2.2.32/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-deflate --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-balancer --enable-proxy-http
make
sudo make install
```

Start Apache:

```
sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
```

**Check, if everything is OK**

Navigate to http://localhost in your browser, where you should see a message saying “It works!”.

Alterntively, you can do this via terminal:

```
wget -qO- http://localhost | grep "It works!"
```

Which should output something like this in the terminal:

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

**Make Apache start at boot time**

```
sudo cp /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl /etc/init.d/apachectl
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/apachectl
sudo sed -i '2i #\n### BEGIN INIT INFO\n# Provides:             apache2\n# Required-Start:       $remote_fs\n# Required-Stop:        $remote_fs\n# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5\n# Default-Stop:         0 1 6\n# Description:          apache2\n# Short-Description:    The Apache webserver\n### END INIT INFO' /etc/init.d/apachectl
sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d apachectl defaults
```

Hint: you can call apachectl with **sudo service apachectl** now.

**Secure Apache**

```
sudo service apachectl stop
sudo adduser --system apache
sed -i -e 's/User daemon/User apache/g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
sed -i -e 's/Group daemon/Group nogroup/g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
sudo service apachectl start
```

**Check new settings**

```
ps -aux | grep httpd
```

If the terminal output of the last command shows some lines starting with "apache" then everything is OK.

**Configure your site(s)**

If you want to configure your apache for just one site, simply edit the httpd.conf

```
nano /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

The essential parameters you may want to modify are:

```
ServerName www.example.com:80
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If you want to configure more than one site, have a look at httpd-vhosts.conf

```
nano /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

You will have to add a < Directory > section withing the < VirtualHost > similar to the one above, but for the document root of the VitualHost. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
    <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hey Johano, this is an excellent tutorial; thank you so much for sharing this.

I have one question about configuring httpd-vhosts.conf. In your instructions below this part, you write the command as: `nano /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`. Did you mean to write `nano /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf`? If so, this file does not exist after completing installation and needs to be created.

Comment: Upon further research, I think the correct path for this file is `/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. I will edit your post to reflect this.

Comment: Hi Matt, sorry I missed your question. Thanks for correcting the path.

Answer (score 0):

### How to install Apache 2.2.34 (Ubuntu 14.04.x ... 16.04.4 or later):

1. Install new zlib:

   ```
   wget http://www.zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
   tar -xvf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz     
   cd zlib-1.2.11/    
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local 
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
2. Install apache 2.2.34:

   ```
   wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.2.34.tar.gz   
   tar -xvf httpd-2.2.34.tar.gz 
   cd httpd-2.2.34/ 
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-deflate --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-balancer --enable-proxy-http 
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
   ```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2019, I did the following to install Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04:

Add old Repos to sources.list:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Used the command "apt-cache madison ^apache2 | grep "2.22" to find the appropriate version details

Then

```
  apt install apache2.2=2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1 apache2-mpm-worker=2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1 apache2.2-common=2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1
```

Commented out the modules not available, and went from there.  I note that some of the modules needed to be installed - apt-cache madison ^libapache2 helped find them. Also I have issues with authz - presumably because I was not starting from a clean config.

Answer (score 0):

## If the main reason you want to downgrade Apache to version 2.2 instead of using 2.3, 2.4 or higher is configuration compatibility, just install and enable `mod_access_compat` to ensure your old configs work as expected.

Do you want to install Apache 2.2 because some of the syntax for configs have changed beginning with Apache 2.3? I was scared of doing this myself at one point, but honestly it’s fairly straightforward how to change configs from old to new [as explained here on the official Apache site](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html).

But if you simply don’t have the time — or you are not really comfortable doing that — then look into using the `mod_access_compat` module. As explained on [that page I linked to above](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html):

> **Mixing old and new directives**
>
> Mixing old directives like [`Order`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order), [`Allow`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#allow) or [`Deny`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#deny) with new ones like [`Require`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) is technically possible but discouraged. [`mod_access_compat`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) was created to support configurations containing only old directives to facilitate the 2.4 upgrade. Please check the examples below to get a better idea about issues that might arise.

I would recommend installing Apache 2.4 but enable `mod_access_compat` and then — if and when time is available — go through the Apache configs you have and “modernize” them to use Apache 2.4 compatible config options.