# Apache from 2.4.7 to 2.4.10

Tags: upgrade, apache2

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS that runs Apache 2.4.7.  I know that Apache 2.4.12 is out but only want to upgrade to Apache 2.4.10.   How can I do this without breaking WordPress 4?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Installation details for specific package versions on Ubuntu can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version).

As for the breaking Wordpress 4 I can't find any know bugs right away. However if you are really nervous then do the upgrade in a test environment first.