# Anyone able to help me figure out what I'm doing wrong with installing Standard ML

Tags: software-installation, paths

I'm a bit lost.  Typically getting something programming related working on Ubuntu is painless while Windows always a pain.  Not the case this time around.  I followed the instructions from here...

http://smlnj.org/dist/working/110.79/index.html

"The only file you need to download manually is config.tgz. Unpack, configure by editing config/targets, and install by running config/install.sh."

I added a folder to home with the label "smlnj", extracted the files and then ran the setup

After that, I added the path...

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/home/andyd/smlnj
```

When I type "sml" at the terminal, I get the following message...

"The program 'sml' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install smlnj"

Not sure why I'm getting that.  I would be totally fine with just doing apt-get but I need version 117.90 for class and apt-get keeps installing 117.82.

Anyone able to help me with this?  I'm still a bit of a novice when it comes to Linux

Comment: Have you checked [this page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version) out? It tells you how to install a specific version - it's for Apache but the information should still be good.

Comment: I haven't but thanks!  I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `INSTALL` file:

> ```
>  2.5.  What needs to be on my PATH?
>  ----------------------------------
>
>  - You should include $d/bin into your PATH.
> ```

i.e. if you have installed into directory `d=/home/andyd/smlnj` then you should `export PATH=$PATH:/home/andyd/smlnj/bin`

*BTW it is bad practice to use `sudo` to edit files in your own user directory, and bad practice to use plain `sudo` at all with GUI applications like `gedit`: it can lead to unexpected file ownership issues.*

Comment: In regards to your comments - I actually just searched on Google and saw someone else mention sudo gedit to change / add paths on here.  I'll keep that in mind though.  So the recommended method is to edit in the terminal window with something like Vim?

Comment: @AndD it's fine to use gedit - *without* sudo - on your own files. For system files (where elevated privileges *are* required), gedit may be used with `gksudo` or (since that appears to have been deprecated) `sudo -H` although yes personally I tend to use a terminal based editor such as vi or (more often), `sudo nano`.

Comment: Ok good to know.  Thank you for the additional info!