# How to install gcc 4.1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Tags: gcc, versions

How can I install the old version of gcc (gcc-4.1.2) on Ubuntu?  ( without Synaptic ) .My actual version of gcc is gcc-4.4.7

Comment: The default compilers , Ubuntu 16.04 are : 1) The system compiler g++ = version 5.3.1 , 2) g++-4.7 , 3) g++-4.8 , 4) g++-4.9 . ..... ? What is the purpose of gcc-4.1.2 ? ?

Comment: I am trying to compile some old program that is using ver 4.1.2 of gcc and is incompatible with the newest versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Assume a 64bits Ubuntu 16.04 .

Available is {gcc-3.4.6, g++-3.4.6} ... This version is very close to gcc-4.1.2 .

gcc34 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRTkzQnRSNXZ6UVU/view?usp=sharing

g++34 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNV3J3bnVoWGNWdG8/view?usp=sharing

Clik the packages, compat-gcc34-3.4.6-ubuntu1204-1_amd64.deb and compat-gcc-34-c++_3.4.6-20_amd64.deb : They will then be installed.

Using, examples : 1) `$ export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 && [other command]` ... like 2) `$ export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 && ./configure` .... and 3) `$ gcc34 file.c`

? Which application is it that requires gcc-4.1.2 ?

---

Comment: On Docker and Ubuntu16.04 I end up with a `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables` after installing the `.deb` packages via `dpkg -i`.

Comment: @loretoparisi : Please specify your "Ubuntu16.04" : Is it a 32bits OS, or is it 64bits ?

Answer (score 0):

Possible dupe of this question: [How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version)

First, find the exact name of the version of `gcc` you wish to install by running:

```
sudo apt-cache madison ^gcc
```

Then find the version you want and run:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc=VERSION
```

Finally, run this command to check which version of `gcc` you installed:

```
dpkg -l 'gcc*' | grep ^i
```

Note: This may cause some dependency issues.