# APT install package with dependency

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I created own debian packages with dependencies.

Package A:
Version 1.0 depends on Package B = 1.2
Version 1.1 depends on Package B = 1.2

Package B: Version: 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3

If I'm trying to install Package A with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f <PACKAGE A> #So the version 1.1 with B = 1.2 is picked
```

the following 'error-message' has been output:

```
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
<PACKAGE A> : Hängt ab von: <PACKAGE B> (= 1.2) aber 1.3  soll installiert werden
```

I understand the error-message, but is there a way to bypass it? To allow to install a 'outdated' dependency?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I know how to install a custom version. My intension is to use that command out of a C++ program. I could also use `apt-cache depends <PACKAGE>` but there is the version missing

Comment: Is package B 1.3 backward compatible with 1.2? if yes you could be less strict in your debian/control to depends on <PACKAGE B> (>= 1.2)

Comment: No, thats the problem.