# Installing a previous version of proftpd on ubuntu

Tags: apt, versions, proftpd

I am trying to install a `previous version (1.3.5)` of `proftpd` on ubuntu to exploit an inherit vulnerability and following [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version). For checking what versions are available to apt-get, I ran

```
apt-cache policy proftpd
```

with output

```
proftpd:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: (none)
Version table:
```

I ran command

```
apt-cache madison proftpd
```

and the output:

```
aneela@aneela-VirtualBox:/etc/network$ sudo apt-cache madison ^proftpd
proftpd-mod-dnsbl | 0.1.5-3ubuntu1 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-odbc | 1.3.5~rc3-2.1ubuntu2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-pgsql | 1.3.5~rc3-2.1ubuntu2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-doc | 1.3.5~rc3-2.1ubuntu2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-tar | 0.3.3-1build2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-ldap | 1.3.5~rc3-2.1ubuntu2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-case | 0.7-1build1 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-geoip | 1.3.5~rc3-2.1ubuntu2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-mysql | 1.3.5~rc3-2.1ubuntu2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-basic | 1.3.5~rc3-2.1ubuntu2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-vroot | 0.9.2-2build2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-clamav | 0.10-1build2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-autohost | 0.4-1build2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-fsync | 0.2-1build2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-sqlite | 1.3.5~rc3-2.1ubuntu2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-mod-msg | 0.4.1-1.1build1 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
proftpd-dev | 1.3.5~rc3-2.1ubuntu2 | http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

I didn't understand the output of `policy` but `madison`gave me the exact version I need to install. When I tried

```
apt-get install proftpd=1.3.5~rc3-2.1ubuntu2\*
```

It says `version not found.`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you have? That package is available in 14.04. Newer releases exist for later Ubuntus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the package is not found, the most likely scenario is that it is not available for your Ubuntu version (16.04?), as newer versions of Ubuntu move on to more updated packages, eliminating old ones from the repositories. Alternatively, your Ubuntu is too old (12.04?). As I said in my comment, the version you want is available for 14.04 (trusty).

To get around this you can get the specific version from the trusty repositories. There are two ways to do this.

1. You could add `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. However, this might be dangerous, because some install/updates/upgrades could draw from both releases when it should not (e.g. packages no longer recommended in 16.04 yet available in 14.04 can be now installed).
2. If you only need one package, then it is better just to download the package itself and install manually. For your case, check [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=proftpd) site. The specific file you need seems to be [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/proftpd-basic). To install, download the **.deb** file for your architecture. Then open a terminal, go to the folder where the file is, and run:

   `sudo dpkg -i file.deb`

   `sudo apt-get install -f`

Then, you should have the version you want.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to install two of its dependencies, libmemcached10 and libmemcachedutil2 and it worked fine.