# How to install the same version of a package on different machines?

Tags: apt, package-management

I need to run cppcheck on several machines with different versions of Ubuntu. Normally I install cppcheck with `sudo apt-get install cppcheck`.

Well, one of the machines is running Ubuntu 16.04. An other is running Ubuntu 16.10.

I figured now out, that my installation process installs different versions on the machines. One machine has cppcheck 1.72-1, the other machine has cppcheck 1.75-2. I already found out, that this is a normal behavior. You can even check the installation candidates [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cppcheck&searchon=names).

Well, I need the same version an all machines. So I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version): `sudo apt-get install cppcheck=1.72-1`. But then I get the error: `E: Version '1.72-1' for 'cppcheck' was not found`

Comment: Why do you want the same version? Newer releases rarely have older versions packaged for them. Worst case, you can try downloading the specific package file and installing it using `dpkg -i`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
apt-get download cppcheck
```

to download the deb-package file and install this on different machines with

```
apt install ./cppcheck_1.72-1_amd64.deb
```

But this is not always working if (for example) decencies to library-versions or other packages are not met on one of the destination machines.

Comment: You need in total 3 packets:
  cppcheck libtinyxml2-2v5 python-pygments