# How to install HWE Kernel with a specific kernel version

Tags: kernel

I have installed HWE kernel by using

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

This automatically installs the latest kernel in my case "Linux 4.13.0-45-generic x86_64" which is normal.

But How can I have specific kernel version while installing HWE.

**Note**: I require this since one of my application supports kernel from 4.13.0-26 to 4.13.0-34 kernel. 
Though this can be done by downgrading manually. Is there a command to achieve this for automation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-16.04=<specific_version_[num|name]>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version)