# Installing previous version of program: chromium-browser

Tags: 18.04, server, xfce, chromium

I have an old computer that doesn't support the newest versions of Chromium, since the CPU lacks the support of SSE3 instructions (I saw that in a forum).

Recently, I have updated Chromium and version 89 was installed, and then stopped working (Illegal instruction error).

Which commands should I run in order to reinstall an older version of chromium (e.g. 65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu1), which doesn't contain SSE3 instructions?

Did anyone experience this also?

Of course, in order to install an older version of Chromium, I have to make sure that all the dependencies are installed in the correct version, and not in a newer version...

**EDIT:**

After uninstalling Chromium (`sudo apt remove` all the packages below), I ran:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser=65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu1 chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra=65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu1 chromium-codecs-ffmpeg=65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu1 chromium-browser-l10n=65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu1

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chromium-codecs-ffmpeg : Conflicts: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra but 65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra : Conflicts: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg but 65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As you see, my installation has some kind of problem...

How can I solve this?

By the way, I have a functional Firefox browser in my old computer, fortunately...

Comment: If the device is so old that it is incapable of running a current version of the browser, it probably shouldn't be connected to the internet.  Along with that, if you have to also roll back a lot of dependencies to get it to work, you will probably break *other* software.  Maybe google has an archive of older versions, but it would be best to isolate it from the rest of your system, like using a VM container.  The best path is to connect only devices that can run current versions of software.  The old versions will have security holes that people know how to exploit...

Comment: Oddly, you might want to check to see if current Vivaldi works for you. I have been told that it does pretty well with older hardware, but have no way to verify this personally.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version):

```
sudo apt-get install chromium=65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu1
```

should work!

Also, `apt` automatically solves dependencies.

Comment: The package `chromium` is apparently not available (see `apt-cache search`). I have edited the question with more details...