# How can I upgrade a package to a specific version?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, headless

I know how to [*install* a specific version of a package](https://askubuntu.com/q/92019/1060743). Now I want to upgrade all packages of my system with:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

But for a specific package, I do not want it to upgrade to the latest version, but to a specific one. E. g., currently installed version is 1. Latest available via `apt` is 3. I want to upgrade to 2. Is it possible with `apt`?

Comment: You can hold a package, and then control the version manually.

Comment: Currently there is no upgrade available for `gitlab-runner` for any release of Ubuntu in the Ubuntu repositories. If you are using Ubuntu sources, `apt upgrade` won't change that package no matter how hard you try. To see for yourself, examine the output of `apt policy gitlab-runner`

Comment: @ArturMeinild If I hold it, it won't upgrade at all, right? Do you know what I have to tell `apt` afterwards to upgrade it to a specific version?

Comment: @stackprotector if you use `aptitude` and search for the package, down at the bottom of the description it shows the available versions. If you highlight the version you want and press +, it will set that version to be installed.

Comment: Yes then you unhold, upgrade manually, and hold again to prevent apt from upgrading.

Comment: If this Version you wish is available through apt you can pin It with apt-pinning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [nobody's helpful comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1504489/how-can-i-upgrade-a-package-to-a-specific-version#comment2639361_1504489), pointing to [apt-pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto), I was able to come up with the following solution:

You can pin a package to a specific version by creating a preference file for it (e. g. `/etc/apt/preferences.d/my-package`) with the following content:

```
Package: my-package
Pin: version 2
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

This will tell `apt` to not upgrade package `my-package` to a greater version than `2`.